# How to style Theme.Holo.DialogWhenLarge to custom size, position, margins, etc.?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am working on my first Android app (only worked on iOS and WP before) and trying to show an activity in fullscreen on phones and and as dialog/popup on tablets. I found Theme.Holo.DialogWhenLarge and it seems that this is what I was looking for.

The activity is displayed as dialog on tablets but I did not found out how to change the size and position of the activity. It is simply shown at screen center and has about the same size and dimensions as on the phone. How can this be changed? Is this done by the Activity directly or do I have to create a sub-style?

I had a look on [Theme.Holo.DialogWhenLarge](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values-large/themes.xml). This Theme simply applies PreferencePanel.Dialog to preferencePanelStyle. I do not understand how this influences the activity to be shown as Dialog. What is this PreferencePanel?

How can I find out in general what kind of properties of an object (view/activity) can be changed by a style?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I didn't find any way to override the width and height styles on the xml.
The only way I found is to change the window on the onStart, here is the code:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // In order to not be too narrow, set the window size based on the screen resolution:
    final int new_window_width = 505;
    final int new_window_height = 502;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layout = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
    layout.width = new_window_width;
    layout.height = new_window_height;
    getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(layout);
}
```

Hope it helps!